# Where is console.log output when running app on android real device in react native

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, reactive-programming

I am currently working on a project. In that project, I am printing **console.log**  but no messages are printing anywhere.

I am using **npm and react-native-cli** to run on a real android device.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you use a simulator, you can press Cmd + M (on Android) or Cmd + D (on IOS) to see the "Debug JS Remotely",

If you use a real device, you should shake the device and you can see the "Debug JS Remotely" option.

"Debug JS Remotely" option will popup Chrome and from there you can use the Developer Tools.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging

Answer (score 2):

Below are the ways to check the Console messages in React Native. Once you run the application:

For Android:

1) For real device, shake so that you can view the Developer Options. For a simulator, press ⌘M (Mac) or Ctrl+M(Windows) to bring up the same. Press "Debug JS Remotely", which would open Chrome Debugging. You can then view the Console of Chrome's developer tools to check the messages.

2) Open Android Studio, and in the Logcat window for your device/simulator you can view all the messages including Console logs.

For iOS:

1) For real device, shake so that you can view the Developer Options. For a simulator, press ⌘D (Mac) to bring up the same. Press "Debug JS Remotely", which would open Chrome Debugging. You can then view the Console of Chrome's developer tools to check the messages.

Answer (score 0):

run command **react-native log-android** to see all logs in react native.

**or**

use **debug js remotely** in developer menu to see logs

for more details debugging visit
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging#chrome-developer-tools